# how to display the data from database for multiple images

Tags: php

> html

```
 <a href="samcheckdb.php"><img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1007" alt="image" id="img1"></a></li>
```

> samcheckdb.php

```
        <?php
        $hostname="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="tiger";
        $itemId=intval(\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'itemId'));
        * @var $dbhandle type */
       $dbhandle = \mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

        /* @var $select type */
         $select= \mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample")
     or mysqli_error($dbhandle);
     $sql="select subtitle,descript from dessert where itemId='oepd1007'"; 
      $result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $subtitle=$row['subtitle'];
    $descript=$row['descript'];
     mysqli_close($dbhandle);
     ?>
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Customer menu card</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dessert.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id='custdisp' name='custdisp' method='post' action="samcheckdb.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="d"><?php echo $descript ?></div>
        <div id="s"><?php echo $subtitle?></div>
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

> I'm able to retrieve the corresponding data from the database with this code.But im having n number of images,it is not possible to create that many number of pages and i dont think it is optimal.How can i do this for multiple images???

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript for this.

Comment: You need some sort of handler that will check the image click, jQuery or Javascript. Then AJAX to make a connection with PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can put an onclick like

```
<img src="getimage.php?itemId=oepsv1007" alt="image" id="img1" onclick="get_detail('oepsv1007');">
```

then do a ajax call to get the detail using this id.

javascript function

```
function get_detail(id) {
  // ajax call
}
```

Comment: without ajax,is it possible to achieve using javascript alone?im not familiar with ajax..

Comment: @user3516005 Without AJAX you'll need to do a standard `POST` to the server (also possible with javascript). There's no real reason, however, to not use AJAX in this situation.

Comment: if you need to fetch detail from database, you need to do an ajax call to get data from server.

Comment: @Biswajit Technically that's not true. You don't *need* AJAX, it's just a lot more seamless than `POST`.

Comment: if i need to fetch data from database it is not totally possible with javascript alone?I need ajax..I'm i right?

Comment: @user3516005 You need some way of actually transferring data to your server (ie, the request to fetch db data), so your options are AJAX or a traditional `POST` request, both can be driven with javascript.

Comment: @user3516005, you realize that ajax is javascript right?

Comment: yeah i have created this,but i have n number of images and for each image do i have to create a seperate page?

Comment: what do you mean by "separate page"?
for each image onclick send id as method parameter and use that parameter to get specific detail.
only 1 function may solve your problem.